# Tkinter Widgets Not Moving When Window is Resized

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm just diving into Python and Tkinter, and I grabbed this code directly out of a TkDocs.com tutorial.

My understanding is that with the grid method set up as it is, and the rowconfigure and columnconfigure methods set the way they are (0, weight=1) the grid should resize when the window resizes, and the widgets inside the grid should move accordingly. This is how the tutorial explains it, but this isn't what happens when I run the program. Widgets don't move at all when the window is resized. As this is unmodified code I'm at a loss as to what could be going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

I'm on Windows 10 running using the PyCharm IDE, in case that's relevant.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        meters.set(int(0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Feet to Meters")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

feet = StringVar()
feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=feet)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

meters = StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equivalent to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): 
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

feet_entry.focus()
root.bind("<Return>", calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've only given weights in the root window. The frame `mainframe` grows and shrinks as you would expect. Since you didn't add weights to rows and columns in `mainframe`, they won't change.

In other words, make sure to configure the weight in every widget that has children managed by `grid`.

I don't know how you want it to behave when you resize things vertically, so I'll assume you only want the items to scale horizontally in the following example.

```
mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

If you want the button to always be in the bottom-right, you can add leave row between the button and the entry widgets empty and give that row a positive `weight`.

```
ttk.Button(...).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)
...
mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error (spurred on by Bryan's answer, which pointed me in the right direction) I was able to find the issue.

This line...

```
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
```

...was the culprit. The sticky statement in there prevented the widgets from moving within the grid cells when the window was resized. Remove that, and the program functions as described in the tutorial. I'm perplexed as to how an error like this slipped by whomever wrote up the tutorial, but hey, we're all human.